# Rails and arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

Here is problem : 
`Order` object has two attributes which defined as array of string (`list_of_products`, `quantity_of_product`). Also `Order` has_many `line_items` and has_many `products` through `line_items`.

This is `show_receipt` action in `Public` controller:

```
 def show_receipt 
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  @order.sum = 0.0
  @order.quantity = 0
  @order.quantity_of_product = []
  @order.list_of_products = []
  @order.line_items.each do |item|
     @product = Product.find(item.product_id)
     @order.list_of_products << @product.name
     @order.sum += (item.quantity*item.price).to_d
     @order.quantity += item.quantity
     @order.quantity_of_product << item.quantity.to_s
     @product.unite = @product.unite - item.quantity
     @product.save
   end 
     @order.save
end
```

it works fine, when I `debug(@order)` in the view of `show_receipt` action I can see those two arrays (`list_of_products` and `quantity_of_product`). Both are NOT empty. But when I `debug(@order)` in the view of `../orders/@order` there are two arrays but one of them (`list_of_products`) is empty and the other one  (`quantity_of_product`) is NOT empty?

Here is `Order` class:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer
    has_many :line_items
    has_many :products, :through => :line_items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
 end
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you render/check for validation errors after the saves? Any errors?

Comment: `@order.valid?` says `true`

Comment: Some things are confusing me - | 1 | You're defining `quantity_of_product` & `list_of_products` as empty arrays *after* you call the `find` method. Shouldn't they be populated already? | 2 | How are you populating your record when you show in the view? Currently, you're using `show_receipt` to SAVE data -- surely this is hugely inefficient?

Comment: @Peck Thanks for your notification. You are right. I changed my approach. And I also should change the way I populate records. Could you let me know more about using `show_receipt` for saving data (you said it is huge inefficient). Appreciate your help.